# Error with tiny-dnn for pedestrian recognition

Tags: c++, computer-vision, deep-learning, tiny-dnn

I'm working on a security system and I need to classify if the detected motions are caused by humans or something else like light wind…

To do that i originally used a **MLP** with keypoints, but then I decided to switch to a convolutional neural network so I've tried to use the **tiny-dnn** library for C++, but always with bad results.

Here is the network:

```
net << conv<relu>(80,240,1,1,56)            // conv1 0
    << max_pooling_layer<relu>(80,240,56,2) // max1 1
    << conv<tan_h>(40,120,1,56,64)          // conv2 2
    << max_pooling_layer<relu>(40,120,64,2) // max2 3
    << conv<tan_h>(20,60,1,64,72)           // conv3 4
    << max_pooling_layer<relu>(20,60,72,2)  // max3 5
    << conv<tan_h>(10,30,1,72,55)           // conv4 6
    << max_pooling_layer<relu>(10,30,55,2)  // max4 7
    << conv<tan_h>(5,15,1,55,27)            // conv5 8
    << fc<identity>(2025,333)               // fc1 9
    << fc<tan_h>(333,90)                    // fc2 10
    << dropout_layer(90,0.5)                // dropout 11
    << fc<softmax>(90,out);                 // fc3 12
```

To train it I use 1200 images with persons and 1200 with random background parts (I've randomly shuffled the dataset), I've tried to change the **optimizer**, the **learning rate** and the **batch size**, but when i test it with 500 postive images and 500 negative images, I always get as result only one class with a slightly different confidence for each image. What could be the problem?

Comment: What if you test with the 1200+1200 images that you trained with – are they classified (mostly) correctly? For how many epochs do you train? How (if at all) does the training error decrease while training?

Answer (score 1):

In general, *the amount of pictures* you are using to train a DNN from scratch *seems really small.* For that purpose, you should consider perhaps a tenfold increase.

An alternative is to use the same approach as the fast-learning classification services like [vize.it](http://vize.it/), namely **pretraining your neural network** with an existing model from [a model zoo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo) and just finetuning it for your task; by a naive application you probably won't get as good results as existing services, but it should get you started.

But first, you should make a few easy sanity checks to make sure you are not making an even more basic mistake:

- **Use the same kind of images for training and testing.** It's not clear from your question whether you just randomly split your data or use images from different sources - if the latter, do the images look really similar?
- **Can your network overfit?** What if you ask it about the images you used for training?  You should be getting crisper predictions for these - if so, the advice above definitely applies.
- **Can your network overfit on a simple task?** Try feeding it much smaller images, say just 2 or 10.  Can your network recognize these images back?  If still no luck, you probably have a data processing issue or making some mistake with your framework.  If this works, it's time to tweak the optimization parameters some more.

Good luck!